# Sign in as user from a non interactive batch process

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to use Identity Server (using ASP.Net Identity) as the authentication server for a number of services. One of these is a non interactive service that runs batch jobs on behalf of users. The batch jobs are scheduled by users via an interactive session (web site/mobile device). To process the job the service needs a valid token to access other services. However, the job can run months after it was originally setup and it is therefore not possible to use the token from the original interactive session.

Does Identity Server/OIDC provide a mechanism for handling this scenario? The ASP.Net Identity Sign In Manager has a method for signing in a user without their password. This could be used to provide an API method on the Identity Server to allow authenticating as a user without the password (provided the client has the required scope). Is this a valid approach?

Comment: An interactive service can't run on behalf of users and (while scheduled by) most likely won't require consent from the user. So there is IMO no reason why you can't simply include the user's identifier (sub) as part of the request. If the resource is unable to verify whether the client has access to the user's information, then you can use [delegation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) (contact the service that does have this information), and use a new token which includes the sub claim.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at using the client credentials of the process to obtain tokens via delegation that are valid for the user's subject id.